# Hair coming through the mesh?

Tags: particles, hair

Why the hair particles coming through the mesh. With the hair particles and object as a mesh. Why the particles coming through the mesh. The Ear is separate mesh still the mesh coming through. I weight paint the area. Any suggestion or help how to control it. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

### Particle System Settings:

- Check "Advanced"
- Check "Rotation"

  1. Orientation Axis: Normal-Tangent
- Children

  1. Simple -> Interpolated
- Render

  1. Under "Object" check "Object Rotation"

### Hair strand object:

- Viewport Header Tool Settings
  [image]

  1. Options
  2. Under "Affect Only" check "Origins"
- Move the origin to the root of the hair strand object
- Unset "Affect Only Origins"
- Rotate the hair strand object with pressing : **R Y 90**

Comment: Thanks for details answer.