# Am I over thinking hair in 3.6?

Tags: hair

I've been wrestling with hair on my character for, well, too long. I used photos from wig companies as guides as they are the only source I can find with multiple views of styles. Now, I was fighting hair going over ears on a short, choppy bob cut when I got to thinking that maybe I'm over thinking this. I'm going through a bunch of manipulations to get any duplicate/interpolated hair from passing through the ear itself, even though the outer strands would lie well. Maneuvering those guide hairs creates a bulge, which has that domino effect of having to manipulate every guide around it to smooth out the bulge and, you never really get that right as every "correction" creates two more problems. So I'm thinking, it may not even matter if some of the hairs go through the ear as they are covered anyway...unless that creates problems later on in animation/rendering. So, does it even matter if lower layer hairs go through covered/unseen parts of the ear? Or am I overthinking this thing?[image]

Comment: These questions might provide you with a solution: [Question 1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62122/how-do-i-stop-hair-particles-going-through-the-body-and-the-head) / [Question 2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172309/hair-coming-through-the-mesh)

Comment: Thanks but that's not it. The hair is evenly spaced over the head and the only point that a guides children enter the surface are at the ear...unless I'm manipulating the curve around the ear far enough. I'm wondering if I should even be concerned with some of the guide curves children penetrating the skin given that they really wouldn't be seen.  Would this create a processing problem later or, is it purely a cosmetic I shouldn't worry about?